# Sort array of string 00:00:00

Tags: c#, string

I have got some array like

"00:00:00"

"00:02:00"

"00:07:02"

Which is the best approach to sort it like AZ?

Thanks!!!

Comment: That depends on the exact nature of the data represented by those strings. Can you describe this in more detail?

Comment: `yourArray.OrderBy(e => e)`? if you want good answers, ask good questions.

Comment: you could probably convert the strings to `TimeSpan`...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Do u think I have to convert to TimeSpan first and then to sort it. Correct?

Comment: @Peretz If you don't need to use it as a `TimeSpan` object, then there's no need to convert it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am lazy so I would probably go like that:

```
string[] array = new string[] { "00:03:00", "00:00:00" };
Array.Sort(array);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing datatype is a `TimeSpan`, in which case you could use

```
var sortedArray = myArray.OrderBy(TimeSpan.Parse);
```

Comment: This a nice usage of leaving out the Element in OrderBy. How did they call this dynamic invoking thing?

Comment: @Silvermind not sure what it's called, the only real difference between this and using using `i => TimeSpan.Parse(i)` is you're not creating an extra delegate.

Comment: I'm sorry I have to say, I think the extra delegate is still created but automatically. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Silvermind I was told it wasn't, I'll look it up.